# Integration test for enum generated from database

Tags: c#, t4

I am generating enum type from SQL database table using t4 template

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Status(Id INT NOT NULL, 
[Name] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL)
```

T4 template

```
 public enum <#= tableName #>
{<#  
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
string command = string.Format("select {0}, {1} from {2} order by {0}", columnId, columnName, tableName);
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(command, conn);

conn.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
bool loop = reader.Read();

while(loop)
{#>         [Description("<#= reader[columnName] #>")]
    <#= Pascalize(reader[columnName]) #> = <#= reader[columnId] #><# loop = reader.Read(); #><#= loop ? "," : string.Empty #><#  
}#>  }
```

generated enum

```
[GeneratedCode("TextTemplatingFileGenerator", "10")]
public enum Status
{
    [Description("status1")]
    Placed = 0,
    [Description("status2")]
    Started = 1,
    [Description("status3")]
    Paused = 2,
    [Description("status4")]
    Approved = 3,
    [Description("status5")]
    Rejected = 4,
    [Description("status6")]
    Invoiced = 5,
}
```

is there any better way to write integeation test which will tell me if database values and c# enum goes out of sync ?

Comment: How are you testing now?  I don't see an integration test in your example.

Comment: I don't have automated test , At the moment i have post deployment SQL script to update values in db where I comment that please regeneate ENUM if you add/update values